# iOS get full resolution AVFoundation in preview

Tags: avfoundation

I would like to process a full resolution (3264x2448) image frame during preview in real time. So far the highest resolution I can get is by setting:

`self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureSessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080;`

Is there a way I can set to full resolution? how?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried setting the preset to `AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh` (the default)?

Comment: Yes, I did but that only give me 1920x1080 and I have iphone6 which native raw resolution should be 3264x2448

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture full sized images, instead of adding an  `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`, add a `AVCaptureStillImageOutput` instead:

```
captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto

let stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
captureSession.addOutput(stillImageOutput)

captureSession.startRunning()

let connection = stillImageOutput.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)

stillImageOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(connection) { (sampleBuffer, error) in
    // sampleBuffer contains high res image
}
```

This may not be "real time" enough for you. This only gives you images when you call `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection`.